# How can I send an HTTP POST request to a server from Excel using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, http, post, serverxmlhttp

What VBA code is required to perform an HTTP POST from an Excel spreadsheet?

Answer (score 176, accepted):

```
Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
URL = "http://www.somedomain.com"
objHTTP.Open "POST", URL, False
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
objHTTP.send ""
```

Alternatively, for greater control over the HTTP request you can use [`WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384106%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in place of [`MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms762278%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: For greater control over the HTTP request you can use "WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1" instead of "MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP"

Comment: Noteworthy is that you can also use this to issue a HTTP PUT by changing "POST" to "PUT".  Content to PUT goes in the .send() method.  Any additional headers you need to set can be done also following syntax used in the User-Agent example.

Comment: Please don't use parentheses around parameters if you do not use the Sub's return value: VBA Syntax do not allow parentheses around Sub's parameters (they are needed for Functions, though), so these parentheses are actually arithmetic parentheses used to clarify operator precedence. Apart from being misleading and unclear, this can eventually result in a runtime error if the argument is an object. And although not explicitly asked for, usually you would want to use the HTTP response, which you could mention can be retrieved by `objHTTP.responseText`.

Comment: @Leviathan the parens actually do more than that: they make the VBA runtime *evaluate the expression as a value*, and *pass it to the method ByVal* **regardless** of whether the method's signature says `ByRef` or not. That's why using them with object variables of a type that doesn't have a default member causes run-time errors; and using them on an object that *does* have a default member, passes that default member's value instead of the actual object.

Comment: how about a json payload ...how can we pass that in send ?

Comment: The suggestion to use WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1 saved my bacon, as the MSXML classes wouldn't allow me to retrieve more than one Set-Cookie header from a server response to my request. Thanks!

Comment: A million times thank you. I don't know why, because I didn't see it in any other examples, but the "User-Agent" header was crucial for me, because otherwise the body wasn't being sent in my request.

Answer (score 60):

In addition to the answer of [Bill the Lizard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158633/how-can-i-send-an-http-post-request-to-a-server-from-excel-using-vba#158657):

Most of the backends parse the raw post data. In PHP for example, you will have an array `$_POST` in which individual variables within the post data will be stored. In this case you have to use an additional header `"Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`:

```
Set objHTTP = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
URL = "http://www.somedomain.com"
objHTTP.Open "POST", URL, False
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
objHTTP.send "var1=value1&var2=value2&var3=value3"
```

Otherwise, you have to read the raw post data on the variable `"$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"`.

Comment: I am trying to post this request (with curly braces) and get compilation errors ...can u pls help: "{"request":{"carName":"Honda","model" : "1A5"}}"

Comment: @fiddle did you URL encode that string?  The curly braces are less of a concern than the quotes (which would terminate the strings in the VBA")

Answer (score 59):

If you need it to work on both Mac and Windows, you can use QueryTables:

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;http://carbon.brighterplanet.com/flights.txt", Destination:=Range("A2"))
    .PostText = "origin_airport=MSN&destination_airport=ORD"
    .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
    .SaveData = True
    .Refresh
End With
```

Notes:

- Regarding output... I don't know if it's possible to return the results to the same cell that called the VBA function. In the example above, the result is written into A2.
- Regarding input... If you want the results to refresh when you change certain cells, make sure those cells are the argument to your VBA function.
- This won't work on Excel for Mac 2008, which doesn't have VBA. Excel for Mac 2011 got VBA back.

For more details, you can see my full summary about "[using web services from Excel](http://numbers.brighterplanet.com/2011/01/06/using-web-services-from-excel/)."

Comment: +1: I only need it on Windows but a cross-platform solution might benefit somebody else.

Comment: I don't think you can actually access the html code, you can only get the information on the rendered web page (not the actual html code)

Comment: +1 for the cross-platform solution and +1 (if I could) for the full summary with gist link and all. Thanks!!

Comment: I had to support both windows and mac, and this solution was right on! Note that when you specify PostText, the URL should process POST requests, otherwise it should process GET requests.

Comment: Is it possible to output the results to a variable instead of a Range ? Need to do some Json parsing.

Answer (score 16):

To complete the response of the other users:

*For this I have created an **"WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1"** object.*

Send a post request with some data from Excel using VBA:

```
Dim LoginRequest As Object
Set LoginRequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
LoginRequest.Open "POST", "http://...", False
LoginRequest.setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
LoginRequest.send ("key1=value1&key2=value2")
```

Send a get request with token authentication from Excel using VBA:

```
Dim TCRequestItem As Object
Set TCRequestItem = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
TCRequestItem.Open "GET", "http://...", False
TCRequestItem.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/xml"
TCRequestItem.setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/xml"
TCRequestItem.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Bearer " & token
TCRequestItem.send
```

Comment: David, once you send the request, how do you read the response?

Comment: Response is inside `TCRequestItem Object`, you can read it like: `TCRequestItem.ResponseText` after doing `TCRequestItem.send`

Comment: Please, @david.q, from where did come that "token" variable?

Answer (score 8):

You can use `ServerXMLHTTP` in a VBA project by adding a reference to `MSXML`.

> 1. Open the VBA Editor (usually by editing a Macro)
> 2. Go to the list of Available References
> 3. Check Microsoft XML
> 4. Click OK.

(from [Referencing MSXML within VBA Projects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms763701(v=vs.85).aspx))

The [ServerXMLHTTP MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms762278(v=vs.85).aspx) has full details about all the properties and methods of ServerXMLHTTP.

In short though, it works basically like this:

> 1. Call [open](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms763809(v=vs.85).aspx) method to connect to the remote server
> 2. Call [send](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms755436(v=vs.85).aspx) to send the request.
> 3. Read the response via [responseXML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms757055(v=vs.85).aspx), [responseText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms763684(v=vs.85).aspx), [responseStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms759211(v=vs.85).aspx) or [responseBody](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753682(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: that link uses jscript, not VBA

Comment: Thanks @JohnHenckel. I've made some changes to bring that answer up to date.

Answer (score 1):

I did this before using the MSXML library and then using the XMLHttpRequest object, see [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20060904064108/http://scriptorium.serve-it.nl/view.php?sid=40).

Comment: File not found.