# getHTTP with (Excel) VBA?

Tags: html, excel, vba, httpwebrequest, excel-web-query

I'm searching for a query for an Excel VBA macro to get a web page's HTML source code as a string.

I've found some source with `getHTTPrequest` but I can't register .net framework `system.dll` or link it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Close enough: [How can I send an HTTP POST request to a server from Excel using VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158633/how-can-i-send-an-http-post-request-to-a-server-from-excel-using-vba) — It's even for Excel ;-)

Just use a GET request instead:

```
objHTTP.Open "GET", URL, False
```

MSDN: [Using the WinHttpRequest COM Object - Retrieving Data Using Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384072(VS.85).aspx)

Answer (score 6):

Here's a compact function that returns the response text of almost any specified URL, such as HTTP source code for a web page, or response text from [JSON API's](https://any-api.com/).

---

### *Late Bound:* <sub><sup>*(No references required)*</sup></sub>

```
Public Function getHTTP(ByVal url As String) As String
  With CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0") 
    .Open "GET", url, False: .Send
    getHTTP = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
  End With
End Function
```

---

### *Early Bound:*

If you need to call the function repeatedly (in a loop, for example) you might be better off to use it as an early-bound function:

1. **Add a reference** to the XML library:

   <kbd>Tools</kbd> → <kbd>References</kbd> → Select  `Microsoft XML, v6.0` *(or the highest version you have listed)*
2. Declare a **module-level variable**: (place this line at the top of a module)
   <sup>(Shortcut to create new VBA module: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> → <kbd>`I`</kbd> → <kbd>M</kbd>)</sup>

   `Dim msXML As XMLHTTP60`
3. Within the function, only **create the XML object** if the variable is not already set:

   ```
    Public Function getHTTP(ByVal url As String) As String
      If msXML Is Nothing Then Set msXML = New XMLHTTP60
      With msXML
        .Open "GET", url, False: .Send
        getHTTP = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
      End With
    End Function
   ```

---

### *Example Usage:* <sub><sup>(for either method)</sup></sub>

To get the HTML source code for this page:

```
Debug.Print getHTTP("https://stackoverflow.com/q/817602")
```

---

> ️ **NOTE!**
>
> Many applications (including **MS Office**) will now return an error if you attempt to connect to an insecure url with methods like this, or others (ie., Excel's `WEBSERVICE`).
>
> To avoid this issue, **use `HTTPS://` instead of `HTTP://` wherever possible.**

Comment: This answer has helped me out a lot. Thanks! I've referenced the *Late Bound* solution in a follow-up question here: [Return server error from function as string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62584612/return-server-error-from-function-as-string).

Comment: Please do not endorse the [`StrConv(, vbUnicode)` nonsense](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14292880/11683). The only way this may produce a sensible result is if `.responseBody` happens to be a byte array in the same codepage as the current codepage for non-Unicode programs in Windows, or a byte array in UTF-8 that happens to only have the first 127 ASCII characters in it. In all other cases this will produce garbage. What you should have used instead is the `.responseText` property.