# Return server error from function as string?

Tags: excel, vba, http, error-handling, excel-2016

I have an Excel VBA function that takes a URL and returns a response (source: [getHTTP with VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52903455/10936066)).

```
response = GetHTTP(.ListColumns(colNameURL).DataBodyRange(n).Value)

...

Public Function GetHTTP(ByVal url As String) As String

  With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    .Open "GET", url, False: .Send
    GetHTTP = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
  End With

End Function
```

The function works as expected.

---

However, if there is a problem with the URL (like the server being down), then the VBA editor pops up an error dialog.

```
Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)': Uspecified error
```

Instead of popping up a dialog, I would like the function to return the error message as a string.

Is there a way to return the server error as a string (without doing the HTTP call more than once)?

---

What I've tried:

I can get the function to return a pre-defined error message (from a constant).

```
Public Const InvalidURL = "Problem with URL or Server"


Public Function GetHTTP(ByVal url As String) As String

On Error GoTo ConnectionError:

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", url, False: .Send
        GetHTTP = VBA.StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
    End With

On Error GoTo 0

Exit Function

ConnectionError:
GetHTTP = InvalidURL

End Function
```

But that's not quite what I'm looking for. I want to return the true runtime error message (example: the error from the server).

Comment: You need to wrap an error handler around the `Open()` call

Answer (score 1):

It was pretty simple:

```
GetHTTP = "Problem with URL or server: " & Err.Number & " " & Err.Description
```

Here's the full function:

```
Public Function GetHTTP(ByVal url As String) As String

On Error GoTo ConnectionError:

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", url, False: .Send
        GetHTTP = VBA.StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
    End With

On Error GoTo 0

Exit Function

ConnectionError:
GetHTTP = "Problem with URL or server: " & Err.Number & " " & Err.Description

End Function
```