# VBA Script to convert from internet explorer to Edge or chrome browser

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, microsoft-edge

I am looking for below code to covert from internet Explorer to Edge browser, request for you help to sort the same.

```
Sub CHECK_STATUS()
 
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim IntExp As Object
    
    Set IntExp = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IntExp.Visible = False
 
    For Each cell In Range("A2:A20000")
        'Here A2 is cell Address where we have stored urls which we need to test.
        
        If Left(cell.Value, 4) = "http" Then
            
            ' Goto web page
            IntExp.navigate cell.Text
            
           ' Below loop will run until page is fully loaded
            Do While IntExp.Busy Or IntExp.readyState <> 4
                DoEvents
            Loop
 
            ' Now use text which you want to search , error text which you want to compare etc.
            Dim ieDoc As Object
            Set ieDoc = IntExp.document
            
            If ieDoc.getElementsByClassName("box-content").Length <> 0 Then
                cell.Offset(, 1).Value = ieDoc.getElementsByClassName("box-content")(0).innerText 
            End If
        End If
    Next cell
 
    IntExp.Quit
    Set IntExp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31302304/will-microsoft-edge-support-com-automation-internetexplorer-object).

Comment: The Tag is confusing and I am working as entry level with selenium

Comment: Your current code is not complex and it is fairly intuitive how to convert to selenium basic. I would recommend spending a day or two researching selenium basic and you will be good to go. The tasks you need are 1) instantiate a webdriver instance;  2 ) navigate (`.get`) to an URI; 3) `FindElementsByClass` method call;  4) `.quit` .I suggest you start with [this](https://codingislove.com/browser-automation-in-excel-selenium/) and [these](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=wiseowl+selenium)

Comment: That will give you more than you need. Your conditional logic will remain the same. You don't need the waits as there are inbuilt implicit waits though you can specify explicit wait times.

Comment: Can you pls help me write the code? Want to take value from Cell range "A" for url and print the value / result which required to Cell range "B"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use **SeleniumBasic** to automate Edge in VBA. SeleniumBasic is a Selenium based browser automation framework for VB.Net, VBA and VBScript.

I agree with QHarr's comments, you can also follow the steps below to automate Edge browser with SeleniumBasic:

1. Download the latest version of SeleniumBasic v2.0.9.0 from [this link](https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic/releases/tag/v2.0.9.0) and install it.
2. Download the corresponding version of Edge WebDriver from [this link](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/).
3. Find the path of SeleniumBasic which is `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\SeleniumBasic` in my computer (it might also be in this path `C:\Program Files\SeleniumBasic`), copy the Edge WebDriver `msedgedriver.exe` to this path.
4. Rename `msedgedriver.exe` to `edgedriver.exe`.
5. Open Excel and write the VBA code.
6. In the VBA code interface, click **Tools > References**, add **Selenium Type Library** reference and click **OK** to save.
7. I write a simple VBA code to show how to automate Edge using SeleniumBasic. You can refer to it and change the code according to your own demands:

```
Public Sub Selenium()
    For Each cell In Range("A2:A20000")
        Dim bot As New WebDriver
        If Left(cell.Value, 4) = "http" Then
            bot.Start "edge", cell.Value
            bot.Get "/"
            If Not bot.FindElementsByClass("box-content") Is Nothing Then
                cell.Offset(, 1).Value = bot.FindElementsByClass("box-content")(1).Text
            End If
        End If
        bot.Wait 3000
        bot.Quit
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: How do I take value from cell range?

Comment: I want to take the value from A row and print the value in B row

Comment: @mohammedBaig The functions of taking value and setting value in cells are the same as what you write in IE VBA scripts. For example, if you want to take value form A1 cell, you can use `Range("A1").Value`. If you want to set values in B row, you can use `Cell.Offset(, 1).Value = xxx`. Please check my updated code sample.

Comment: Hi @YuZhou, i think you have not got my point, i want to open url from Cell "A" and get classname text and paste Cell B, this programm i want to loop till last entry.

Comment: @mohammedBaig What I write is just a simple example. I don't know what exact urls you're using, so I can't make a test. I have told you how to do it and you only need to make some changes according to my code. I have told you how to get value from cell A, how to set value in cell B and how to find elements by classname. Please try to edit your code according to my answer.

Comment: @mohammedBaig I've managed to change the code according to your original code. Please check the updated code in my answer.

Comment: how can I introduce multiple links to process for your reference below are links:
https://ok.ru/video/1810319018655
https://ok.ru/video/1807388510879
https://racaty.net/0mwf8fsz54yw
https://racaty.net/0y4snx47bgd4
https://racaty.net/1300hs4l556d
https://racaty.net/1j8xbp0xtvp1
https://ok.ru/video/2030651443930
https://ok.ru/video/1128245626153
https://ok.ru/video/2547172574672
https://ok.ru/video/1390379797030

Comment: I tried to place elsif its not working, its only taking single web, I want to introduce different url with different classname or xpath

Comment: If the elements you want to search have different class names in every link, I think you can't loop once to get them all. You can only get them one by one.

Comment: No other way to find them via loop ?

Comment: I'm afraid not.

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped to run as background process via Task Scheduler.

Answer (score 3):

I had been using IE and Internet Object Model (IOM) to achieve automation with internal web-based systems in my works at bank. Since the announcement that IE will be no longer supported by Microsoft at 15 June 2022, I started to look for possible alternative solutions on the internet.
After investigation, I found that there are two solutions to achieve automation on Edge browser : 1) SeleniumBasic or 2) Win API. Though SelenimBasic seems to be the mainstream suggestion at forums, Win API can be regarded as better solution in several different ways, especially for my own situations.

*Pros of Win API Solution :*

- No need installation and regular update of Edge driver.
- Able to automate with multiple existing Edge browser windows (which have been opened before program start).
- Most of codes in existing IOM solution can be preserved and re-applied. It is because both solutions of IOM and Win API should use HTML Document Object Model (DOM) at last to achieve automation on webpage. The difference is on the way to find browser and attain HTMLDocument from browser.

*Cons of Win API Solution :*

- We can automate with “webpage” on Edge browser but not the “Edge browser” itself. It is not like IOM and SeleniumBasic that can control web browser. For this, I use Shell function and DOS commands to achieve automation of opening and closing Edge browser.
- The webpage has to be opened in IE mode at Edge browser which means this solution is subject to Microsoft’s future direction on IE mode of Edge browser.

*Sharing on my experiences to use Win API on Edge browser webpage automation :*

1. Place the following codes in a new blank module. I name this module as “MsEdge” usually. The codes in this module are no need to modify for usage. You can directly use the codes even if you don’t know much about Win API.

   ```
   Public lngProcessID_Close As Long

   'Part 1 --- Locate IES

   Private strHwndIES As String

   Private lngHwndIndex As Long

   Private Declare Function EnumWindows Lib "user32" ( _
       ByVal lpEnumFunc As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long

   Private Declare Function EnumChildWindows Lib "user32" ( _
       ByVal hWndParent As Long, ByVal lpEnumFunc As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long

   Private Declare Function GetClassName Lib "user32" Alias "GetClassNameA" ( _
       ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal nMaxCount As Long) As Long

   'Part 2 --- Get HTMLDocument from IES

   Private Const SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG = &H2

   Private Const GUID_IHTMLDocument2 = "{332C4425-26CB-11D0-B483-00C04FD90119}"

   Private Declare Function RegisterWindowMessage Lib "user32" Alias "RegisterWindowMessageA" ( _
       ByVal lpString As String) As Long

   Private Declare Function SendMessageTimeout Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageTimeoutA" ( _
       ByVal hWnd As Long, _
       ByVal msg As Long, _
       ByVal wParam As Long, _
       lParam As Any, _
       ByVal fuFlags As Long, _
       ByVal uTimeout As Long, _
       lpdwResult As Long) As Long

   Private Declare Function IIDFromString Lib "ole32" ( _
       lpsz As Any, lpiid As Any) As Long

   Private Declare Function ObjectFromLresult Lib "oleacc" ( _
       ByVal lResult As Long, _
       riid As Any, _
       ByVal wParam As Long, _
       ppvObject As Any) As Long

   'Part 3 --- Check Process Name

   Private Declare Function GetWindowThreadProcessId Lib "user32" ( _
       ByVal hWnd As Long, lpdwProcessId As Long) As Long


   Public Function findEdgeDOM(Title As String, URL As String) As Object

       'Find criteria-hitting Edge page in IE mode

       Dim hwndIES As Long

       Do

           hwndIES = enumHwndIES

           If hwndIES Then

               Set findEdgeDOM = getHTMLDocumentFromIES(hwndIES)

               If Not findEdgeDOM Is Nothing Then

                   If InStr(findEdgeDOM.Title, Title) * InStr(findEdgeDOM.URL, URL) Then

                       Do

                           hwndIES = enumHwndIES

                       Loop While hwndIES

                       Exit Function

                   Else

                       Set findEdgeDOM = Nothing

                   End If

               End If

           End If

       Loop While hwndIES

   End Function

   Public Function enumHwndIES() As Long

       'Get all hwnds of IES

       If Len(strHwndIES) = 0 Then

           EnumWindows AddressOf EnumWindowsProc, 0

           lngHwndIndex = 0

       End If

       'Exit function when overflow

       If lngHwndIndex + 1 > (Len(strHwndIES) - Len(Replace(strHwndIES, ",", ""))) Then

           enumHwndIES = 0

           strHwndIES = ""

           Exit Function

       End If

       'Return IES hwnd one by one

       enumHwndIES = CLng(Split(Left(strHwndIES, Len(strHwndIES) - 1), ",")(lngHwndIndex))

       lngHwndIndex = lngHwndIndex + 1

   End Function

   Private Function EnumWindowsProc(ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Boolean

       Dim lngProcessID As Long

       GetWindowThreadProcessId hWnd, lngProcessID

       EnumChildWindows hWnd, AddressOf EnumChildProc, lngProcessID

       EnumWindowsProc = True

   End Function

   Public Function EnumChildProc(ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Boolean

       Dim strTargetClass As String, strClassName As String

       strTargetClass = "Internet Explorer_Server"

       strClassName = getClass(hWnd)

       If strClassName = strTargetClass Then

           If GetObject("winmgmts:").ExecQuery("Select Name from Win32_Process WHERE ProcessId='" & lParam & "' AND Name='msedge.exe'").Count Then

               strHwndIES = strHwndIES & hWnd & ","

               lngProcessID_Close = lParam

               EnumChildProc = False

               Exit Function

           End If

       End If

       EnumChildProc = True

   End Function

   Private Function getClass(hWnd As Long) As String

       Dim strClassName As String

       Dim lngRetLen As Long


       strClassName = Space(255)

       lngRetLen = GetClassName(hWnd, strClassName, Len(strClassName))

       getClass = Left(strClassName, lngRetLen)

   End Function

   Public Function getHTMLDocumentFromIES(ByVal hWnd As Long) As Object

       Dim iid(0 To 3) As Long

       Dim lMsg As Long, lRes As Long

       lMsg = RegisterWindowMessage("WM_HTML_GETOBJECT")

       SendMessageTimeout hWnd, lMsg, 0, 0, SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, 1000, lRes

       If lRes Then

           IIDFromString StrPtr(GUID_IHTMLDocument2), iid(0)

           ObjectFromLresult lRes, iid(0), 0, getHTMLDocumentFromIES

       End If

   End Function

   Public Sub closeEdge(Title As String, URL As String)

       'Close a Edge browser (the last one in EnumWindows order) with criteria-hitting webpage

       lngProcessID_Close = 0

       Dim findEdgeDOM As Object

       Dim hwndIES As Long

       Do

           hwndIES = enumHwndIES

           If hwndIES Then

               Set findEdgeDOM = getHTMLDocumentFromIES(hwndIES)

               If InStr(findEdgeDOM.Title, Title) * InStr(findEdgeDOM.URL, URL) Then

                   Shell "TaskKill /pid " & lngProcessID_Close

                   Do

                       hwndIES = enumHwndIES

                   Loop While hwndIES

                   Exit Sub

               End If

           End If

       Loop While hwndIES

   End Sub
   ```
2. Apply the functions in “MsEdge” module. There are a few application examples for you. Suggest to place and test below codes at another module:

   ```
   Sub findEdgeDOM_DemoProc()

       'Demo Proc : Use findEdgeDOM Function to get DOM of specific Edge webpage by Title AND URL

       'Dim docHTML As MSHTML.HTMLDocument     '--- Early Binding

       Dim docHTML As Object                   '--- Late Binding

       Set docHTML = findEdgeDOM("Enter Part of Webpage Title Here", "Enter Part of Webpage URL Here")
       ‘You can fill just one argument with either part of webpage title or URL as keyword to search for the target browser and leave another one blank (“”). If you provide both title and URL, the funcitons return DOM of the only browser that meets both criteria.

       If Not docHTML Is Nothing Then Debug.Print docHTML.Title, docHTML.URL

   End Sub

   Sub goEdge()

       'Go through every Edge webpage (opened in IE mode) and print out hwndIES, webpage Title & webpage URL

       Dim hwndIES As Long

       'Dim docHTML As MSHTML.HTMLDocument     '--- Early Binding

       Dim docHTML As Object                   '--- Late Binding

       Do

           hwndIES = enumHwndIES

           If hwndIES Then

               Set docHTML = getHTMLDocumentFromIES(hwndIES)

               Debug.Print hwndIES, docHTML.Title, docHTML.URL

           Else

               Debug.Print "Procedure End"

           End If

       Loop While hwndIES

   End Sub

   Sub openEdgeByURL_DemoProc()

       'Open Edge browser to specific URL

       openEdgeByURL "Input Webpage URL Here"

   End Sub

   Public Sub openEdgeByURL(URL As String)

       'Please change the path to your msedge.exe location in your PC

       Shell "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe -url " & URL, vbNormalFocus

   End Sub

   Sub closeEdge_DemoProc()

       'Close Edge browser

       closeEdge "Enter Part of Webpage Title Here", "Enter Part of Webpage URL Here"

   End Sub
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Using a full heavy-weight web browser to do HTTP requests was probably a mistake in the first place, and now is a good opportunity to correct it.

Here is a stackoverflow question on how to do HTTP requests from Excel: it works the same in VBS.

[getHTTP with (Excel) VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/817602/gethttp-with-excel-vba)