# Connecting Edge / Chrome to VBA

Tags: excel, vba, google-chrome, microsoft-edge

I have a code in VBA that I've always used to open Internet Explorer, copy the information on an specific website and than paste in a cell. The issue now is that the website now is no longer working with IE.

I'm trying to adjust this code to use that with Edge and / or Chrome (I already installed Selenium) but I'm actually struggling with it.

Can someone help me to adjust that code?

```
Option Explicit


Sub Test()


    Dim IE As Object
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    Sheets("Sheet3").Select
    Range("A1:A1000") = "" ' erase previous data
    Range("A1").Select


    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        With IE
            .Visible = True
            .Navigate "https://google.com" ' should work for any URL
            Do Until .ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
        End With


        IE.ExecWB 17, 0 '// SelectAll
        IE.ExecWB 12, 2 '// Copy selection
        ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Text", link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
        Range("A1").Select
        IE.Quit

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

How I switch the IE mentions to a Edge or Chrome one? For instance, change IE to objEdge, etc..

Comment: Plenty of info to be had via Googling "VBA selenium" - eg. https://www.guru99.com/excel-vba-selenium.html

Comment: How have you tried to adjust it so far? Where did you run into trouble with it? Please include that in your question.

Comment: Please don't ask [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70370499/connecting-chrome-edge-with-vba) again without improving it. Try to focus on a specific issue where you're stuck, not a broad coding problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use **SeleniumBasic** to automate Edge in VBA. SeleniumBasic is a Selenium based browser automation framework for VB.Net, VBA and VBScript.

You can follow the steps below to automate Edge browser with SeleniumBasic:

1. Download the latest version of SeleniumBasic v2.0.9.0 from [this link](https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic/releases/tag/v2.0.9.0) and install it.
2. Download the corresponding version of Edge WebDriver from [this link](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/).
3. Find the path of SeleniumBasic which is `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\SeleniumBasic` in my situation (it might also be in this path `C:\Program Files\SeleniumBasic`), copy the Edge WebDriver `msedgedriver.exe` to this path.
4. Rename `msedgedriver.exe` to `edgedriver.exe`.
5. Open Excel and prepare to write the VBA code.
6. In the VBA code interface, click **Tools > References**, add **Selenium Type Library** reference and click **OK** to save.
7. Example VBA code (you can change it according to your demands):

   ```
   Public Sub Selenium()
       Dim bot As New WebDriver
       bot.Start "edge", "https://www.google.com"
       bot.Get "/"
       bot.Wait 5000
       bot.Quit
   End Sub
   ```

Reference link: [VBA Script to convert from internet explorer to Edge or chrome browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69118936/vba-script-to-convert-from-internet-explorer-to-edge-or-chrome-browser/69128482#69128482)

Comment: Thanks a lot, Yu Zhou! This worked fine! I was trying to use driver. instead bot. as I saw in all the other references I checked.