# What is the Method for Downloading a Web Page Due to the Retirement of IE 11 in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I have an extensive VBA macro in Excel that is used to open a IE URL and download the page. It uses `CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")` and the `URLDownloadToFile` function of "urlmon". The purpose of this macro is to do the following:
Takes the URLs from the Export sheet, calls SSRS (Reporting Services) to display the report, and downloads the report to a file with the path and name provided on the Export sheet. This results in a set of files, one for each report, with parameters, chart, and data table in the file.

Here are the relative code snippets from the macro:

```
If Cells(ActiveCell.row, 3).Value = "" Then
    Call IE_Automation0(URL & "&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=EXCEL&rc:Toolbar=false", Cells(7, 9).Value + IIf(Right(Cells(7, 9).Value, 1) = "\", "", "\") + Cells(ActiveCell.row, 2).Value) ' change 20120327        
Else
    Call IE_Automation0(URL & "&rs:Command=Render&" & theFormat & "&rc:Toolbar=false", Cells(ActiveCell.row, 3).Value + IIf(Right(Cells(ActiveCell.row, 3).Value, 1) = "\", "", "\") + Cells(ActiveCell.row, 2).Value) ' change 20120327
End If
```

The following is in the IE_Automation0:

```
' Create InternetExplorer Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

' Send the form data To URL As POST binary request
IE.Navigate theURL

Call downloadFile(theURL, theSaveAsFilename + theExtenstion) ' download the SSRS file and save it
```

This is in the downloadFile function which calls the URLDownloadToFile function of urlmon:

```
returnVal = URLDownloadToFile(0, target, strSavePath, 0, 0)
```

What do I need to do to change my code so that I can do the same functions but using Edge, Chrome, or Firefox due to IE being removed in June of 2022.

Comment: If you want to automate modern browsers with VBA, you need to use SeleniumBasic. SeleniumBasic is a Selenium based browser automation framework for VB.Net, VBA and VBScript. You can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70371312/connecting-edge-chrome-to-vba/70375655#70375655) about how to use SeleniumBasic. But I don't find similar function like `URLDownloadToFile` to download file, you can check if the file can be downloaded by pressing **Ctrl+S**, if so, you can use `SendKeys` to simulate key press.

Comment: Can an Excel workbook using Selenium be shared between users, or would they all need to download Selenium?

Comment: They all need to download and install Selenium.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party. But if anyone needs a solution, this might still work.

Declare the DLL in a module.

```
Private Declare Function ShellExecute _
  Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" ( _
  ByVal hwnd As Long, _
  ByVal Operation As String, _
  ByVal Filename As String, _
  Optional ByVal Parameters As String, _
  Optional ByVal Directory As String, _
  Optional ByVal WindowStyle As Long = vbMinimizedFocus _
  ) As Long
```

Then create the Function to use :

```
Function download(URL, ToFile) As Boolean
On Error GoTo feil
download = False
' Parameter for funsjon overføres
    strFileURL = URL                    ' eks "http://norsktipping.n3sport.no/default.aspx?event=GETMATCHINFO&NTMatchId=209562"
    strHDLocation = ToFile              ' eks "file.htm"
 
' Hent filen
    Set objXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
 
    objXMLHTTP.Open "GET", strFileURL, False
    sv = objXMLHTTP.send()
    
    If objXMLHTTP.Status = 200 Then
      Set objADOStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
      objADOStream.Open
      objADOStream.Type = 1 'adTypeBinary
 
      objADOStream.Write objXMLHTTP.ResponseBody
      objADOStream.Position = 0    'Set the stream position to the start
 
      Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        If objFSO.Fileexists(strHDLocation) Then objFSO.DeleteFile strHDLocation
      Set objFSO = Nothing

      objADOStream.SaveToFile strHDLocation
      objADOStream.Close
      Set objADOStream = Nothing
    download = True
    End If
 
    Set objXMLHTTP = Nothing
 Exit Function

feil:
If ActiveWorkbook.ReadOnly Then MsgBox ("Workbook is in read only mode! This result in error when using the dll for web.")
 
download = False
Resume Next
End Function
```

Then you can call for any file URL you want to download like this :

```
Sub testDownloadOfImage()

sv = download("http://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/db-comics/24_1984_web", "C:\Temp\TestImage.bmp")

End Sub
```