# Automating Microsoft Edge in IE Mode using VBA without selenium drivers

Tags: vba

Is there any way to automate Edge in IE mode using VBA without Selenium drivers. Will it work in same way as how it works in IE. We need to use the same code in VBA.

Answer (score 0):

You may like to check out my reply to a similar post here.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/71994505/9791828

This can be done with some upgrades to windows and a small modification to registry.