# Open Edge in IE Mode using VBA

Tags: vba, microsoft-edge

I am trying the @longvh registry solution ([Automating Edge Browser using VBA without downloading Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70619305/automating-edge-browser-using-vba-without-downloading-selenium)) and have a question: Do I need to change the VBA code to open Edge in IE Mode, rather than IE? If so, can anyone provide an example of that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Do I need to change the VBA code to open Edge in IE Mode, rather than IE?

There is no COM interface available for the Edge browser. Microsoft has not provided any way to automate the Edge browser using VBA automation.

So, there is no way to fetch the already opened instance of the Edge browser and retrieve elements with the help of VBA.

Comment: Is there any information whether Microsoft will change that in the future?