# Open Edge In IE Mode

Tags: microsoft-edge

```
Sub Resolve()

    Dim obj As New WebDriver
    obj.Start "Edge", ""
    obj.Get "wwww.website for example.com"
    obj.FindElementById("s_swepi_1").SendKeys (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Actions").Range("J1").Value)
    obj.FindElementById("s_swepi_2").SendKeys (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Actions").Range("J2").Value)
    obj.FindElementByLinkText("Login").Click
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))
    For i = 1 To 1000 ' change 10 to the number of rows you want to loop through
    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Actions").Range("A" & i).Value = "" Then
            MsgBox "Finish"
            Exit For
        End If
        obj.FindElementById("s_1_1_4_0_Ctrl").Click
        obj.FindElementById("1_s_1_l_SR_Id").Click
        obj.FindElementById("1_SR_Id").SendKeys (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Actions").Range("A" & i).Value)
        obj.FindElementById("s_1_1_0_0_Ctrl").Click
        obj.FindElementByName("s_2_1_40_0").ClickDouble
        obj.FindElementByName("s_2_1_40_0").SendKeys (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Actions").Range("D" & i).Value)
        obj.FindElementByName("s_2_1_53_0").ClickDouble
        obj.FindElementByName("s_2_1_53_0").SendKeys (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Actions").Range("B" & i).Value)
        obj.FindElementById("1_s_1_l_Type").ClickDouble
        obj.FindElementByName("s_3_1_43_0").SendKeys (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Actions").Range("C" & i).Value)
        obj.FindElementById("1_s_1_l_Type").ClickDouble
    Next i
End Sub
```

I need your support to help me to modify the mentioned code to open `Edge browser in IE mode` as i tried more that one modification but with no luck.

Comment: share the modifications you have tried or any additional information that you have tried out. This will help to understand the motive and provide a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'll have to say automate IE mode using VBA Selenium is currently impossible. One of the prerequisites for automating IE mode is to define `InternetExplorerOptions` ([doc for reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium/ie-mode?tabs=python#automate-ie-mode-in-microsoft-edge)), which VBA Selenium does not have. However, I have found some possible alternatives for you. Please check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70619305/automating-edge-browser-using-vba-without-downloading-selenium/71994505?noredirect=1#comment128133297_71994505).