# How to populate web forms now that Internet Explorer is gone?

Tags: excel, vba

I've got existing Excel VBA code, that uses "Microsoft HTML Object Library", "Microsoft Internet Controls", and Internet Explorer (IE) to populate a state website's web form (hospital data); it's for a single hospital (so no looping in that sense) at a time, but a ton of data per form.[Example of Page 12 data to be entered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aa72m.jpg)

Any advice on what to pursue now, ideally w/ minimal mods to existing VBA code?

TIA for anything :-)

Note: I do this with IE already running, and already logged into the state website, and with the appropriate web form (aka "page") active.

Here's the opening lines of one of my Subs (for the Page 12 data mentioned above):

```
Sub TWELVE_Internet_form_fill_Part1()
Dim ieDoc As Object
Dim sws As SHDocVw.ShellWindows
Dim strURL As String
Dim n As Integer
'Set main URL to evaluate open IE windows
strURL = "https://siera.oshpd.ca.gov/"
Set sws = New SHDocVw.ShellWindows
'Cycle through all open IE windows and assign the window whose URL matches strURL
For n = 0 To sws.Count - 1
If Left(sws.Item(n).LocationURL, Len(strURL)) = strURL Then
Set ieDoc = sws.Item(n).document
sws.Item(n).Visible = True
Exit For
End If
Next n

'Medicare Traditional Inpatient Daily Hospital Services

ieDoc.all.txtPCL1_5.Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("12 Final").Range("B9")
ieDoc.all.txtPCL1_10.Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("12 Final").Range("B10")
ieDoc.all.txtPCL1_15.Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("12 Final").Range("B11")
ieDoc.all.txtPCL1_20.Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("12 Final").Range("B12")
ieDoc.all.txtPCL1_25.Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("12 Final").Range("B13")
ieDoc.all.txtPCL1_30.Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("12 Final").Range("B14")
ieDoc.all.txtPCL1_35.Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("12 Final").Range("B15")
ieDoc.all.txtPCL1_40.Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("12 Final").Range("B16")
ieDoc.all.txtPCL1_45.Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("12 Final").Range("B17")
ieDoc.all.txtPCL1_50.Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("12 Final").Range("B18")
```

FWIW, I tried using Edge's Internet Explorer mode and the code did not run. Note

Comment: Have you tried Selenium?

Comment: This answer describe few methods how to do it even with Edge: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71994505/453348

Comment: Use python and selenium.