# Send Keys from VBA to chrome by Chrome DevTools Protocol

Tags: excel, vba, google-chrome-devtools, sendkeys, browser-automation

I want to automate Chrome from Excel VBA. I am using the framework mentioned in : (Method 2 in the answer)

[Automating Edge Browser using VBA without downloading Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70619305/automating-edge-browser-using-vba-without-downloading-selenium)

where in github located

https://github.com/longvh211/Chromium-Automation-with-CDP-for-VBA

In the browser I want to automate, there is a search input and looking at the sample I can select the input like this

```
chrome.jsEval "el = document.evaluate(""//input[contains(@placeholder,'Search')]"", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;"
```

And I can change its value like :

```
chrome.jsEval "el.value = """ & WorkSheet.Cells(2, 3) & """"
```

However the input has autocomplete (typeahead) and when I change its value like above, it doesn't filter the table below it. I believe I should send the value by sendkey like in Selenium, but couldn't figure out how to do this with this framework.

I would appreciate any help on this issue.

Comment: Try "el.focus(); document.execCommand('insertText', false, """ & WorkSheet.Cells(2, 3) & """)"

Comment: Try also CDP methods like [Input.insertText](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Input/#method-insertText).

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks a lot for your suggestions, Try "el.focus(); document.execCommand('insertText', false, """ & WorkSheet.Cells(2, 3) & """)"  worked like a charm. Please make it as answer so I can tag it as the answer. Also can you please give advice how can I use CDP methods you have mentioned in your second comment (like Input.insertText) and if there are any samples that I can find for CDP comments, thank you

Comment: And one more question, if you can help. There is a Select2 to choose 1 option, but when I enter the value in it, it shows 2 different values with additional text in it (it has an additional text to the right where that additional value goes to another input) and I have to choose any one of them. Is there a way to select options with CDP? (It doesn't accept the value with the method you suggested even tough you enter the value with additional text)

Comment: I don't know about VBA+CDP, so it might be better if you find that info and post an answer with both approaches.

Comment: OK thank you, I switched to Selenium VBA, it has more documentation and examples