# view-source scrape From Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, view-source

view-source:https://www.walmart.com/ip/Rice-Krispies-Treats-Original-Chewy-Crispy-Marshmallow-Squares-Ready-to-Eat-12-4-oz-16-Count/10818666?athbdg=L1600&from=/search

This is the information I am trying to acquire. I have looked across the web and try different code, the best I've gotten is opening up a Walmart page saying it doesn't support Internet Explorer, or a 210 error.

210 error might be my company's security policy, but kind of at a loss. Any help or attempts or just advice will be appreciated!

```
Option Explicit
Sub WalmartDoesntWorkWithBrowser()
Dim IE As Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate "https://www.walmart.com/ip/Rice-Krispies-Treats-Original-Chewy-Crispy-Marshmallow-Squares-Ready-to-Eat-12-4-oz-16-Count/10818666?athbdg=L1600&from=/search"
Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4
DoEvents
Loop
Debug.Print IE.Document.DocumentElement.OuterHTML
End Sub
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/817614/11683, then refer to the `.responseText` property.

Comment: Welcome Brendan! Read [The Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and earn your first badge!

Comment: Your code works fine but the Walmart website specifically blocks IE as you say. Take Walmart's advice and use Chrome as your browser for screen scraping. Selenium ChromeDriver would be my choice. Ask another question or search the many answers on SO. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba+selenium-chromedriver?sort=Newest&uqlId=73431