# How do I use Amazon itemlookup API with VBA (Excel)

Tags: excel, vba, amazon-web-services

I have a AccessKeyID and a SecretAccessKey, I can't find any working example with VBA on Excel. 
How can one ItemLookup with VBA, someone has a working example. Do I need besides the two keys for anything else?

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing the Amazon API is json/xml over HTTP. I doubt very much there is a freely available VBA interface to this. You'll have to write it yourself.

Here is an example of how to make HTTP requests in VBA (for a POST request, but trivial to adapt to a GET):

[How can I send an HTTP POST request to a server from Excel using VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158633/how-can-i-send-an-http-post-request-to-a-server-from-excel-using-vba)

and you'll need to read the Amazon API docs:

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEcommerceService/4-0/ApiReference/ItemLookupOperation.html

Answer (score 0):

Also see this as a resource, its for SimpleDB/S3, but is a starting point for making Amazon calls from VBA...

http://aws.amazon.com/code/1275