# Perform hidden http-request from vba

Tags: ms-access, vba, dll

I want to perform a hidden `HTTP-GET` request from MS-access,
as simple as possible, without any extra libraries/components.

Just a simple declare all needed.

Has WinHttp left the building??

Comment: did you have a look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158633/how-can-i-send-an-http-post-request-to-a-server-from-excel-using-vba?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a [great page](http://www.tushar-mehta.com/publish_train/xl_vba_cases/vba_web_pages_services/) about that.

Answer (score 3):

Hope this helps

```
 Dim xhr As Object
 Dim webServiceURL As String
 Dim actionType As String
 Dim thisRequest As String
 Dim targetWord As String

 WebServiceURL = "http://services.aonaware.com/DictService/DictService.asmx/"
 actionType = "Define?word="
 targetWord = "Marketplace"
 thisRequest = webServiceURL & actionType & targetWord

 'use late binding
 Set xhr = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")  

 xhr.Open "GET", thisRequest, False
 xhr.Send

 If xhr.status = 200 Then
   Debug.Print xhr.responseText
   MsgBox xhr.getAllResponseHeaders
 Else
   MsgBox xhr.status & ": " & xhr.statusText
 End If

 Set xhr = Nothing
```