# MS Word addin, macro or VBA script for passing word text to remote server, and displaying the response

Tags: vba, ms-word, ms-office, add-in, word-automation

I would like to create a button that the user can press on the MS word toolbar, after this the document text is passed to a remote service, and some tabular data is passed back and displayed to the user.

Which would be the easiest an quickest for creating this? Can a macro do this? Or to display a button in the toolbar I must have an addin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure a macro can do this. Adding a macro button to your toolbar:

http://web.ticino.com/multilingual/creating_a_macro_button.htm

Passing data to a remote service - well, you did not mention the kind of protocol you have in mind, here is an example of how to post a http request by using VBA:

[How can I send an HTTP POST request to a server from Excel using VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158633/how-can-i-send-an-http-post-request-to-a-server-from-excel-using-vba)