# vba run java class

Tags: java, excel, vba, macos

How can I run a java class from VBA.  I am trying to post to a server using Excel VBA.  I can do this only with VBA on a PC but when using a MAC the `DomDocument` object returns a compile error.  So what I did was create a java class which will post and get a response from the server.  Now what I am trying to do is get the VBA to run the java class wait for a return code and process the return.  If this can be done in a different language (then Java) I am also open to that.  But we prefer Java.

I tried using

```
Dim obj as Object 
Set obj = GetObject("java:SendXML") '(sendXML is class name)
```

but get a run-time error that automation failed.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no need to use Java for doing HTTP POST, you can use standard VBA libraries. See [How can I send an HTTP POST request to a server from Excel using VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/158633/116509).

Edit: If you can't get the Mac answer working, I would advise using CURL which is available for lots of platforms: http://curl.haxx.se/download.html.

Comment: Thanks for the reply however we are doing this on a Mac and the MSXML library doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I tried a similar thing myself, but to me it appeared as if there is (almost) "no way out" of Excel 2012 for Mac. One solution I considered is to use AppleScript, there are a few examples here: http://www.rondebruin.nl/mac.htm

If you could use OpenOffice / LibreOffice you could try [Obba](http://www.obba.info) (Java Object Handler for Excel and OpenOffice). This works for Excel on Windows too and I tried to add Mac support to Obba, but so far found no solution.