# What to reference in place of WinHTTP in Mac Excel 2011?

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I'm trying to download a file from a ftp site and populate an Excel spreadsheet with it. I'm barely familiar with VBA, but I've figured out enough that I know I need to use WinHTTP, or would if this was on a PC. Anyone know a workaround for a Mac? If not is there another way to get a text file downloaded and opened in excel?

```
Sub SourceTextToFile(url As String, toFile As String)
    Dim Request As New WinHttpRequest
    Dim ff As Integer
    Request.Open "GET", url, False
    Request.Send

    ff = FreeFile
    Open toFile For Output As #ff
    Print #ff, Request.ResponseText
    Close #ff
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

See the Query-Tables answer on this question

[How can I send an HTTP POST request to a server from Excel using VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158633/how-can-i-send-an-http-post-request-to-a-server-from-excel-using-vba)

Link to the specific answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4617566/1709223