# Getting "method not valid without suitable object" error when trying to make a HTTP request in VBA?

Tags: vba, rest, excel

I tried to follow this example: http://libkod.info/officexml-CHP-9-SECT-5.shtml - [Archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20151230075839/http://libkod.info/officexml-CHP-9-SECT-5.shtml) - [Donate](https://archive.org/donate/)

but it gave this error

[image: Imgur]

on this line:

```
Dim objHTTP As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP
```

I tried to use this example: [How can I send an HTTP POST request to a server from Excel using VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158633/how-can-i-send-an-http-post-request-to-a-server-from-excel-using-vba)

but it gave this error:

[image: Imgur]

on this line:

```
Print objHTTP.Status
```

So how do I make a POST REST call in VBA? How do I make a PUT multi-part/form-data file upload REST call in VBA?

#### Tools > References

[image: Imgur]

#### Code

```
Sub SendEmail()
    'Dim objHTTP As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP
    'Set objhttp = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    URL = "http://localhost:8888/rest/mail/send"
    objHTTP.Open "POST", URL, False
    objHTTP.send ("{""key"":null,""from"":""me@me.com"",""to"":null,""cc"":null,""bcc"":null,""date"":null,""subject"":""My Subject"",""body"":null,""attachments"":null}")
    Print objHTTP.Status
    Print objHTTP.ResponseText
    
End Sub
```

#### Reference

WinHttpRequest object: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384106(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: The libkod.info domain name recently expired, making the first link unreachable.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You probably haven't added a reference to `Microsoft XML` (any version) for `Dim objHTTP As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP` in the VBA window's Tools/References... dialog.

Also, it's a good idea to avoid using late binding (`CreateObject`...); better to use early binding (`Dim objHTTP As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP`), as early binding allows you to use Intellisense to list the members and do all sorts of design-time validation.

Comment: Ok I added those references and added a screenshot, but it still gives that error. I found that `Set objHTTP = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60` will work, but it still fails at the `Print objHTTP.Status` with 'Method not valid without suitable object.'

Answer (score 14):

I had to use `Debug.print` instead of `Print`, which works in the Immediate window.

```
Sub SendEmail()
    'Dim objHTTP As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP
    'Set objHTTP = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    'Dim objHTTP As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim objHTTP As New WinHttp.WinHttpRequest
    'Set objHTTP = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    'Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    URL = "http://localhost:8888/rest/mail/send"
    objHTTP.Open "POST", URL, False
    objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
    objHTTP.send ("{""key"":null,""from"":""me@me.com"",""to"":null,""cc"":null,""bcc"":null,""date"":null,""subject"":""My Subject"",""body"":null,""attachments"":null}")
    Debug.Print objHTTP.Status
    Debug.Print objHTTP.ResponseText

End Sub
```

Comment: Where can I read about all those different objects. XMLHTTP/XMLHTTP60/WinHttpRequest/WinHttpRequest.5.1/ServerXMLHTTP... ?

Comment: Here's the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384106(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I get connection with server could not be set. :-(

Answer (score 12):

Check out this one:

https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-Web

It's a high level library for dealing with REST. It's OOP, works with JSON, but also works with any other format.

Answer (score 0):

For reading REST data, at least OData Consider Microsoft Power Query. You won't be able to write data. However, you can read data very well.