# hitting REST web service from vbscript

Tags: json, rest, vbscript

**I'm using vbscript to test a REST web service which accepts json as request and responds also in json format. I'm getting HTTP 500 - Internal Server Error as response. Here's the code:**

```
Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
objStream.CharSet = "utf-8"
objStream.Open
objStream.LoadFromFile("C:\request.txt")

restRequest = objStream.ReadText()

objStream.Close
Set objStream = Nothing

contentType ="application/json"

Set oWinHttp = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")

oWinHttp.Open "POST", "http://czcholsint1048.prg-dc.dhl.com:8180/efoms/fulfillOrder", False

oWinHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", contentType

oWinHttp.Send restRequest

response = oWinHttp.StatusText
```

'response' turns out as "Internal Server Error"

I just wonder whether the json i'm converting to string before sending as request is creating any problem. Maybe beacuse of **vbcrlf**'s it has.

Below is the json i'm sending as request:

```
{  
  "fulfillOrderReq": {  
   "hdr": {  
   "messageType": "SALESORDER",  
   "messageID": "d264502f-aaa2-42a5-a38d-c981ccb99379",             "messageVersion": "0.1",  
  "messageDateTime": "2015-03-20 09:48:29",  
  "appId": "OMS",  
  "clientId": "PEP-ESB",  
  "reqCompId": "77000001"  
},  
"bd": {  
  "orders": [  
    {  
      "order": {  
        "orderNumber": "BAYLINETEST512",  
        "salesChannelOrderNumber": "TMALLTEST512",  
        "shopName": "拜仁慕尼黑海外旗舰店",  
        "salesChannel": "天猫订单",  
        "payType": "支付宝",  
        "created": "2015-03-20 15:35:58",  
        "salesChannelMemberName": "mariahliu621",  
        "salesChannelMemberNo": "M-9837423",  
        "idCard": "12312",  
        "idType": "NATIONAL_IDENTIFICATION_NUMBER",  
        "cnee": {  
          "name": "SANTOSH",  
          "address1": "CHINA",  
          "address3": "CHINA",  
          "state": "CHINA",  
          "city": "CHINA",  
          "country": "CN",  
          "postCode": "50470",  
          "telephone": "18610041036",  
          "mobilePhone": "18610041036"  
        },  
        "cneeMemo": "",  
        "cneeMessage": "",  
        "sellerMemo": "",  
        "otherMemo": "",  
        "actualOrderAmount": "792.0",  
        "agioAmount": "0.0",  
        "discountFee": "0.0",  
        "deliveryCost": "70.0",  
        "promotionInfo": "",  
        "orderItems": [  
          {  
            "orderItem": {  
              "productNumber": "184005",  
              "productName": "蜂拥而至CL克 Flock CL gr.",  
              "skuNumber": "184005",  
              "skuName": "Ribéry",    
              "barcode": "",  
              "orderGroup": "0",  
              "productQty": "1",  
              "amount": "75.0",  
              "discountFee": "0.0",  
              "agioPrice": "90.0",  
              "price": "110.0",  
              "taxCharges": "100",  
              "untaxPrice": "50",  
              "dutyCharges": "9",  
              "refundStatus": "Normal",  
              "memo": ""  
            }  
          }  
        ]  
      }  
    }  
  ]  
}  
}  
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make REST call with VBA in Excel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19553476/how-to-make-rest-call-with-vba-in-excel)

Answer (score 2):

You may have seen this already however wanted to share this here since they are related. http://forum.universal-devices.com/topic/4335-vbscript-rest-example/

```
Option Explicit

Dim restReq, url, userName, password

Set restReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")

' Replace <node> with the address of your INSTEON device
' Additionally, any REST command will work here
url = "http://isy/rest/nodes/<node>/ST"

' If auth is required, replace the userName and password values
' with the ones you use on your ISY
userName = "admin"
password = "<yourpassword>"

restReq.open "GET", url, false, userName, password
restReq.send

WScript.echo restReq.responseText
```