# how to synchronize excel sheet which is reside in local folder to web application running locally

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, event-listener

I have requirement of synchronize excel sheet with java.When excel sheet any of the cell changed ,the moment java method (Event listner) should fired.How to do this

Comment: not with apache poi as you have no access to the file while its opened

Comment: Have Excel [POST the changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19553476/how-to-make-rest-call-with-vba-in-excel) to the web app.