# VBA WinHttp component

Tags: xml, excel, vba, winhttp

Here is an issue regarding VBA.

I've scoured my books and searched the web for the answer on this piece of code

```
Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
```

so I've tried countless times to search Google with: WinHttp Object VBA and here some links I visited numbered for you ease

[image: search and visited links]

On number **1** I saw that is called WinHttp reference as you can see that on the red ink on the picture and also that is does not mention VBA as a language on help seen in the blue ink

[image: site visited]

On number **2** there are no information regarding the WinHttp component it has there the WinHttpRequest Object check red ink please.

[image]

I have tried to find it explicitly as **WinHttpRequest.5.1** what is the difference? I have tried to find it as 5.1 but to no avail. Also I was very disheartened to find that if I enter the Object browser in VBE and I search WinHttp I find out the WinHttpRequest there as a property!

[image]

Also do do I have to activate a relevant library from tools references?

It's no secret that I want to pull XML data for financial modeling and I must understand such concepts I've searched other answers and they ask on more advance issues.

Finally can you point me towards a material that writes about VBA-XML interaction a little noob-friendly please.

**Thanks for watching my question**

Comment: See [this Q+A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/158633/1490783), maybe it will help.

Comment: i'm sorry i tried but all i understand is that VBA somehow controls the an HTTP Request and it utilizes the WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1 maybe if you provided me with a brief explanation of this code snipet Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject(WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1            i could understand the rest of the Q+A you have given to me. As you can see in my post i have searched for WinHttp and WinHttpRequest and i have found so many different explanations..where can i found a concrete full description of these code components?

Comment: If you do not understand the fundamental `CreateObject` method, you are already in over your head. This simply creates an instance of an object class ("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1") which assigns it to an object variable: `WinHttpReq`.  You can then use this object variable to control an HTTP request.

Comment: You may want to enable this library reference: http://imgur.com/ezpQHnj

Comment: Wow back just a question guys... well why is the object created as WinHttpRequest.5.1 when i can only find it as WinHttpRequest alone is there a web source that explains the 5.1?

Comment: My question may sound dumb but believe me i scoured the web for it and i find it as this one http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384106(v=vs.85).aspx with a 5.1

Comment: 5.1 is the latest version, so assume that the reference material applies and any breaking changes from previous versions will be noted as needed. Here is some info on the version differences: WinHttp Versions, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384276(v=vs.85).aspx, What's New in 5.1, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384086(v=vs.85).aspx