# Excel to PHP data with Macro

Tags: php, vba, excel, import-from-excel

I am stuck with fetching Excel Realtime Data to PHP.

I followed the Link, and converted Excel to Json inside the Excel it self.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qeFHOe-97fw

Now i want to read Particular Cell Value with PHP using Macro (why Macro? : Which will reduce Saving Excel every second).

I found some solution on that, but some how it's not working with me. 
Reference Tried: [How can I send an HTTP POST request to a server from Excel using VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158633/how-can-i-send-an-http-post-request-to-a-server-from-excel-using-vba)

Can i See Data? (Print or Echo)?
Code: PHP file:

```
<?php
$excelCellA1Value = $_GET["variable"];
echo $excelCellA1Value;
//$data=$excelCellA1Value;
//echo $data;
?>
```

VBA File:

```
    Sub PostData()
    Set objHTTP = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1"
    url = "http://localhost:81/array/post.php?variable="
    objHTTP.Open "POST", url, False
    objHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
    objHTTP.send (Cells(18, 2).Value)
    RunEveryTwoMinutes


End Sub
```

My Question is: How can i read a specific Cell Value with PHP "Real Time" as my Value is refreshing every milliseconds.

Or any Possible way to read realtime data?

Regards
Hardik