# Save data to a website for retreival later

Tags: excel, vba, http, web, powerpoint

I am hoping to add some simple tracking to a VBA macro-based project in PPT. The aim is to know how far users have progressed with some training they need to do.

In theory we could save a text file to a network drive or to their c-drive and review those later (once collected in automatically if on c-drive) but it is all a bit messy.

I'd prefer to be able to share their info with an online location such as a website. I won't have the ability to know or expect a database driver or such so needs to be something Windows can just do (am ignoring macs for now).

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32408328/how-to-send-data-to-website-database-using-vba) as a possible solution to someone asking something similar ...

```
Set objHTTP = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
URL = "http://www.somedomain.com"
objHTTP.Open "POST", URL, False
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
objHTTP.send ("var1=value1&var2=value2&var3=value3")
```

There was no follow-up beyond the above response. Possibly it worked for the OP.

My question is this ...

Assuming the above worked and stored "var1=value" etc. how would I retreive it back out again?

Was there something that needed to be done to "www.somedomain.com" to allow it to receive the data?

I am not a web-developer so feeling bit lost as to what that end of this needs.

Thanks

Simon

Comment: I believe this a task for a database and since you have office, Access is free. Create a table and through a query store the values. Plenty of examples to get you started much simpler than your proposed solution.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for that. I don't have control over the client's PCs etc. I don't know what they have beyond PPT and (therefore) VBA. Not clear where there PPT file would be so can't assume I can create data files of any type (Access or otherwise).