# What tools do I need to learn to manipulate Excel files and update some values into a Web page?

Tags: excel, web, web-applications

To be more detailed, let's say I have an Excel file with some numerical values that need to be updated every day into a Web platform, and I would like to automate this process as it is very time consuming to do it manually. I know some basic Java but that's it, but I'm keen to learn what it takes to improve this process.

Comment: Client side or Server side?

Comment: @RemusRusanu it would be Client Side

Comment: You can simulate Manual updating of the web page using [Internet Explorer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752084(v=vs.85).aspx). Or, more efficient, you can use [XMLHttpRequest object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535874(v=vs.85).aspx). Or, even better (though I know nothing about it) [WinHttpRequest](http://stackoverflow.com/a/158657/4636801).

Answer (score 0):

The is the Java libary [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/) is a mature libary for reading and writing Microsoft Offic documents. Its contains two components called [POI-HSSF and POI-XSSF](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html), that are for handlin Excel files.

If you do not want to insert images or graphs it is relative easy to use.