# VBA to complete a Internet form

Tags: html, excel, vba, internet-explorer

I'm looking for a code to put values from an Excel to a Webpage.

```
Sub FillInternetForm()
  Dim IE As Object
  Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

  IE.navigate "http://xxxxxxxx/"
  IE.Visible = True
  While IE.Busy
    DoEvents  
  Wend
  IE.document.getElementById("xxxxx").Value = "xxxx"
End Sub
```

The error comes in on IE.document.getElementById("xxxxx").Value = "xxxx line and it says Method 'Document' of object 'IWebBrowser 2' failed.

I'm looking for suggstions to solve this question: I made a lot of research and nothing works :/

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: May I suggest a different approach.  Did you see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158633/how-can-i-send-an-http-post-request-to-a-server-from-excel-using-vba

Comment: Try `While ie.Busy Or ie.READYSTATE <> 4`

Comment: @Jeeped thanks for your help. Unfortunately it didn't work :(

Comment: @Miguel thanks for your help. I don't understand how I can applicate the code that you suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ana,
Here is a working example. You can easily customized this little bit of code to work for you. One time you must be aware of is that I added a reference to my project under **TOOLS -> Preferences -> Microsoft Internet Controls**. Also another word of caution is on this line `Set Elements` on this line, if you are looking for something that does not exists you will end up with an error. This working example I put together goes to stack overflow and finds the elements below  `footer-menu`.
Let me know if something does not make sense.

```
Sub TryInternetExplorer()
 'Reference to system32\shdocvw.dll  'Microsoft Internet Controls
Dim IEApp As InternetExplorer
Set IEApp = New InternetExplorer
IEApp.Visible = True
IEApp.Navigate "https://iam.pearson.com/auth/XUI/#login/"
While IEApp.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE And IEApp.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_LOADED
    DoEvents
Wend

'wait for the form to load
Do
Set form = IEApp.Document.getElementsByTagName("FORM")(0) '1st table
DoEvents
Loop While form Is Nothing

 IEApp.Document.getElementsByName("callback_0")(0).Value = "Miguel"
 IEApp.Document.getElementsByName("callback_1")(0).Value = "pass"
 IEApp.Document.getElementsByName("callback_2")(0).Click


Set Document = Nothing
Set IEApp = Nothing


 End Sub
```

Comment: Miguel, when I copy and paste your code and run it, I have this error: 424: object required :(

Comment: Anna did you add the reference as I told you above?

Comment: Set Elements = Document.getElementById("footer- menu").getElementsByTagName("div")

Comment: Thanks in advance for all your help (:

Comment: @ Ana try again there was a space between footer and menu that I most have inserted while copy and paste. I apologize. Make sure that your immediate window is open so you can see the results.

Comment: now your code works :) thanks. but when I try to change and use to my website I get the same error!

Comment: The html code for box that I want to fill up is : <input name="q20_yourEmail" class="form-textbox validate[required, Email] form-validation-error" id="input_20" type="email" size="30" placeholder="ex: myname@example.com" value="" data-component="email">

so i need to use the line like this right?
 Set elements = document.getElementById("input_20").getElementsByTagName("input")

Comment: Ana what is your website I can't help you working in the blind... and please post that html with code tags in your initial post.

Comment: @Ana, I added a comment in code. If you are targeting an input box like the one you suggested you would need to do this instead `IEApp.Document.getElementsByName("q20_yourEmail")(0).Value = "hello"`

Comment: Miguel, I can't give you the website because ti's confidencial. But I applied your new code and now I get a different error: code 91 - object variable or with block variable not set.

Thanks so much for your time

Comment: https://iam.pearson.com/auth/XUI/#login/

you can use this site as example. I need to fill the user name box and password and then click login :) thanks again

Comment: @Anna, I changed the code to an example of navigating to google and then putting my name on the google search box. That is equivalent to what you are trying to do. Please try it and replace the `getElementsByName` with the name of your `input` that should work barring that your webpage has the input box  in the page you are calling.

Comment: it can be a problem if my form is inside another form?

Comment: i'm asking because when I use your code for another pages, it works  ;/

Comment: @Anna, you gave me an example and that's what I used to give you an answer. Yes it matters, because you are targeting individual nodes in a webpage,every web page is different and different things are named differently in other pages. Therefore  your 'FORM(0)' might be `FORM(01)` in your code etc.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation Miguel. when I run the new code I have an error on this line Set form = IEApp.Document.getElementsByTagName("FORM")(0) '1st table 
compile error: expected function or variable :(