# Extracting website data with Excel and VBA

Tags: vba, excel, extract, data-extraction

I want to extract data from a Website and store it in an Excel tablet.
It is a list of suppliers in a register from A to Z. This is the URL: http://www.euroshop.de/cgi-bin/md_euroshop/lib/pub/tt.cgi/Ausstellerverzeichnis_A-Z.html?oid=18864&lang=1&ticket=g_u_e_s_t
The steps I need to take are i.e.: Click B - > Click B2BTrip GmbH -> Extract "Allgemeine Dienstleistungen" and "Sonstiges" into a new row -> repeat with next supplier.
I have an Excel list with all the names of the suppliers and some additional information, where the gathered data should be saved in. [here is a Picture of the list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7ivz.png). Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What have you tried? This is a not a free service where developers just answer your question. This is a collaborative enviroment where we help you solve your problem. That being said, I answer two questions like this yesterday. Start by looking at those and it will give you some basics on doing this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43102290/want-to-select-button-on-website-using-excel-vba/43103158?noredirect=1#comment73315847_43103158 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43095155/vba-to-complete-a-internet-form/43096864?noredirect=1#comment73287856_43096864

Comment: I wanted to hear if this is at all possible to do with vba. Im pretty new to vba so i only have a Basic idea about what it ca do. I was looking for Patterns in the Website to use for the code. For example on every Register site the first entry is on line 2918, next is 2939, 2960, so all 21 lines contain the link to a supplier. but can vba even Access the source code of a Website? I'm sorry if you felt any abuse by my question, I just wanted to get a push in the right direction so I can work it out

Comment: Yes, it is possible. There are countless options to go about this. But the easiest might be to go to the `Data` tab in Excel and click `From Web` (in the section `Get External Data`. But if you want to continue in this direction then your question is off-topic for StackOverflow as this website is only meant for programmers with **specific** coding questions. Otherwise, your post might be more suitable for [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: okay, i'll close this for now then, thank you!