# How do I receive and send messages through Bot Telegram in Excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, telegram, telegram-bot

I wish I could use some macros to send Dashboard summary text over the work Telegram. I know that for me to send by telegram through webhook (GET and POST html) and I researched and found this topic here:
[How can I send an HTTP POST request to a server from Excel using VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158633/how-can-i-send-an-http-post-request-to-a-server-from-excel-using-vba)

```
Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
URL = "https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>/METHOD_NAME"
objHTTP.Open "POST", URL, False
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
objHTTP.send("")
```

Replacing < Token > and < Method_name >

https://core.telegram.org/bots/api

However, when I debug the code it locks up excel and does not come back anymore. Any idea what that might be?

Comment: Are you actually sending anything in the "" ? it might be sending and not receiving a response so just freezing, waiting for something it's not going to get

Comment: In my view, I do not think I need information in this part of send, because it is something that if I access the link ("https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>/METHOD_NAME") the method is already sending Something, the proof that if I play this in the browser I get a message in string.

Comment: is it definitely a POST request you need then and not a GET request?

Comment: Returns the same error using GET and POST

Comment: Try changing the False in the `objHTTP.open "POST", URL, False` to True, to make it asynchronous send. If it still freezes then the error might be deeper than a code problem. You should also try an MSXML2.ServerHTTP60 object to send your requests instead of `ServerXMLHTTP`, that means you can set timeouts for your requests, might be useful for testing.

Comment: It worked when I used ServerHTTP60

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It worked when I deployed MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP to MSXML2.ServerHTTP60.

```
Sub fff()

Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerHTTP60")
URL = "https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>/sendMessage?chat_id="id"&text=test"
objHTTP.Open "POST", URL, False
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
objHTTP.send ("")

Cells(1, 1).Value = objHTTP.ResponseText

End Sub
```