# Web form does not validate when filled with VBA macro

Tags: excel, webforms, vba

I use a Macro to fill in a Webform. So far the Macros serve my purpose. The Web forms gets text the from excel correctly.

The problem is after the form is filled in. The Web form does not recognize the text that the macro inserted. Web forms need an action from the keybord in the Web form to validate that it is not auto filled. For example, if I do anything through the keyboard in the Web form, it then sees as text, so typing space from keyboard and deleting it helps to form to be valid.

How can I use the 'delete' symbol in form? I tried `getElementsByTagName` and `getElementsByClassname` and with this to  `SendKeys` return error. For example,

```
getElementsByTagName(0).SendKeys"{BACKSPACE}"
```

This returns an error.

Comment: I have edited the same so you not knowing English is no longer a problem. The way I see your question is that macro entry to a web form is treated as spam and is not allowed to submit until a keyboard action is triggered which you are trying to do through Macro as well. You should provide additional information as to which web form you are trying to fill. As each web form validation differs.

Comment: Thank you for help :-) Web form validation on site come with changing ClassName of input tag. Probably, ClassName change with javascript action.

Comment: Is it necessary to do it this way? Why not more direct? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158633/how-can-i-send-an-http-post-request-to-a-server-from-excel-using-vba

Answer (score 0):

Prior to using SendKeys Method, you need to confirm that the window and button active is the correct one (you can also use TAB to make sure it is at the correct button) or you can use `ActiveDocument.GoTo(wdGoToPage, wdGoToRelative, 0).Select` and give enough time between keystrokes or the web form to be filled. And then use `SendKeys ("{BACKSPACE}")` . You don't need to associate `SendKeys` to `getElementBysTagName(0)` as it is not a valid method within that object. Just write it plainly

Comment: Here is my HTML code:  `<input class="ng-pristine ng-invalid  ng-touched"  type="text" data-ng-model="textbox">`    And with HTML code i use macro:  `Set inputCollection = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("input")

For Each otext In inputCollection
If otext .getAttribute("data-ng-model") = "text-box" Then
otext .Value = "any text"
otext .focus
SendKeys "{BACKSPACE}"
End If
Next otext `
I think, this web form have an angular validation. And before doing anything from keyboard in this form, ut not valid. I try to use `otext.focus` and `SendKeys "{BACKSPACE}"`, but it do not work.

Comment: Sorry. I am a new member and do not know yet how to type text redable, in column.

Comment: Can anyone to help me?

Comment: use the _edit_ button at the end of your question ... where is says `share` `edit` `flag`  .....  then add your code to the original question  .     indent code by 4 spaces to make it formatted as code   .... after you do that, delete the three comments ( and i will delete this comment)

Comment: Just checking. DId you solve or should i spend time on this.