# Splitting columns doesn't work with button

Tags: excel, vba

For work, I have to pull various information from a USDA report. I have created a sub that will pull the information I need from a text file, into a worksheet "USDA Weekly." I created another sub, using the recorder, that uses text to column to split the information (via fixed width). The sub that does the splitting is the only sub that changes the information on the "USDA Weekly" sheet in any way. All other subs pull information from this sheet.

I have a button on another worksheet (in the same workbook) that runs all the subs I have created for the report I have to do, including the two subs mentioned. Now, when I run sub to split the information it works perfectly however when I click the button to run all the subs including the splitter it doesn't work.

I have run this in the debugger step by step numerous times, in an attempt to figure out why this is happening with no luck. I'm mostly confused as to why it the sub doesn't work when the button is clicked, yet works when run by itself. Any tips as to why this isn't working is appreciated.

Edit: clarification on how this doesn't work. When the splitting sub is run through the button, it does not split the column at all, as shown below. No errors, or anything pop-up.

[image]

Edit Edit: as per Mathieu Guindon (implict) suggestion I have modified formatUSDAWeekly to use a with statement to avoid implicit references.

```
Sub formatUSDAWeekly()
'this sub pulls information from strictly within the workbook

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set wb = ThisWorkbook 'sets wb to the workbook that contains the code (i.e. this workbook)

Set ws = wb.Sheets("USDA Weekly")

With ws

    .Range("A:A").TextToColumns Destination:=.Range("A:A"), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
        FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(39, 1), Array(50, 1), Array(52, 1), Array(61, 1), _
        Array(73, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

End With

End Sub
```

This is the sub for the button

```
Sub start()

Call pullFrom610
Call formatUSDAWeekly
Call formatWIWorkbook
Call formatOSWorkbook

End Sub
```

This is the sub that pulls the information

```
Sub pullFrom610()
'this code was taken from Seamus Abshere
'on SO:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158633/how-can-i-send-an-http-post-request-to-a-server-from-excel-using-vba

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("USDA Weekly")

ws.Columns("A:F").ClearContents 'clears the previous information

With ws.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;https://www.ams.usda.gov/mnreports/lm_pk610.txt", Destination:=ws.Range("A1"))

    .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
    .SaveData = True
    .Refresh

End With

End Sub
```

This is the sub that splits the information using text to column

```
Sub formatUSDAWeekly()
'this sub pulls information from strictly within the workbook

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set wb = ThisWorkbook 'sets wb to the workbook that contains the code (i.e. this workbook)

Set ws = wb.Sheets("USDA Weekly")

ws.Range("A:A").TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A:A"), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
        FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(39, 1), Array(50, 1), Array(52, 1), Array(61, 1), _
        Array(73, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: `Destination:=ws.Range("A:A")` you need to be explicit abut *every* range you use, or it defaults to the activesheet.  That can cause problems once you start to chain different procedures together.  If that's not the issue then it would help to explain exactly how it "doesn't work" - do you see an error or ???

Comment: @TimWilliams thanks for the suggestion! Now, when I run the sub (by itself) on another sheet it works however when I run it through the button it still doesn't work.

Comment: @TimWilliams sorry, I should have been clearer! When I meant not work, I meant that it does not split the text into separate columns. It also does not give any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is probably due to the change of `activeSheet` made by the call to `pullFrom610()` when you click the button.

To solve this, make an explicit call to your `Destination` Range in `Sub formatUSDAWeekly`.

### Edit:

As suggested by @RonRosenfeld, there was a second problem with the query not finishing it's job in time. The solution to this is to put `.BackgroundQuery = False`. The final code will look like this:

```
Sub pullFrom610()
'this code was taken from Seamus Abshere
'on SO:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158633/how-can-i-send-an-http-post-request-to-a-server-from-excel-using-vba

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("USDA Weekly")

ws.Columns("A:F").ClearContents 'clears the previous information

With ws.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;https://www.ams.usda.gov/mnreports/lm_pk610.txt", Destination:=ws.Range("A1"))

    .BackgroundQuery = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
    .Refresh
    .SaveData = True

End With

End Sub

Sub formatUSDAWeekly()
'this sub pulls information from strictly within the workbook

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set wb = ThisWorkbook 'sets wb to the workbook that contains the code (i.e. this workbook)

Set ws = wb.Sheets("USDA Weekly")

ws.Range("A:A").TextToColumns Destination:=ws.Range("A:A"), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
        FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(39, 1), Array(50, 1), Array(52, 1), Array(61, 1), _
        Array(73, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

End Sub
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion! I tried this and while this lets me run the sub (by itself) on another sheet, it doesn't work through the button.

Comment: When you debugged the function step by step, did you discovered in which function the code fail to run?

Comment: the code failed to run in the sub where the code is split, formatUSDAWeekly

Comment: when I ran the start sub step by step, it worked! Yet, when I click the button formatUSDAWeekly did not work, i.e. did not split the columns

Comment: @MathieuGuindon thanks for the links! I have changed my code to include a with statement (I added it the question above), however it still does not work... I'll keep trying to find the implicit reference though!

Comment: @MathieuGuindon it worked!!! :) Thanks for all the help! I'll definitely take a look at those add-ins!

Answer (score 3):

Although there may be a problem with Active Sheet implicit references (and those should be corrected), most likely the problem is that the Query is not finishing before `formatUSDAWeekly` is being called.

There are a variety of possible solutions to this problem including:

- disable `Background Refresh`  `.BackgroundQuery = False`
- use `DoEvents` after the query, but this doesn't always work
- use `.RefreshAll` with a blank query after `pullFrom610` that is named something like `zzzzzz` so it runs last (the queries refresh in alphabetical order)

Comment: Ha, totally missed that!

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I had a similar problem a few weeks ago, and spent some time troubleshooting.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld ooh! That might be it. I'm not going to lie, this is little beyond the scope of my knowledge. When would I disable the background refresh?

Comment: @court_k anywhere before the `.Refresh` member call in the `With ws.QueryTables.Add(...)` block

Comment: ++ Good Catch :)