# Enter Text in Webpage on mouse selection position

Tags: excel, vba

I have this portal where I need to click on 1 to 8 ( as shown in image ) and put "Ok" on position 9.
I managed to do mouse click with the code shown below. However, could not manage to enter text "Ok" on 9th position. Please help. Thanks in advance.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20vrF.jpg)

The requirement is to add the text Ok on the specific position everytime

```
        Public Declare PtrSafe Function SetCursorPos Lib "user32" (ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long) As Long
        Public Declare PtrSafe Sub mouse_event Lib "user32" (ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dx As Long, ByVal dy As Long, ByVal cButtons As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long)
        Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = &H2
        Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = &H4
        Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN As Long = &H8
        Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP As Long = &H10
        'Declare sleep
        Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)

        Sub EnterValue()
          SetCursorPos 250, 250
          mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0
          mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0
          Sleep 50

          '1
          SetCursorPos 475, 350
          mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0
          mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0
          Sleep 50
        '
          '2
          SetCursorPos 550, 350
          mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0
          mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0
          Sleep 50

          '3
          SetCursorPos 625, 350
          mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0
          mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0
          Sleep 50

          '4
          SetCursorPos 700, 350
          mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0
          mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0
          Sleep 50

          '5
          SetCursorPos 775, 350
          mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0
          mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0
          Sleep 50

          '6
          SetCursorPos 850, 350
          mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0
          mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0
          Sleep 50

          '7
          SetCursorPos 925, 350
          mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0
          mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0
          Sleep 50

          '8
          SetCursorPos 1000, 350
          mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0
          mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0
          Sleep 50


        End Sub
```

Comment: The method you use is very unreliable and can break easily (a simple change of screen resolution would probably break it already). Check out [Browser automation in Excel VBA using Selenium](https://codingislove.com/browser-automation-in-excel-selenium/) for a Chrome solution or [Automate Internet Explorer (IE) Using VBA](https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/automate-internet-explorer-ie-using/) for a IE solution to do it properly. Simulating mouse clicks is probalby (sorry to say that) the worst solution to do that.

Comment: Additional to @Pᴇʜ I'd recommend not using web browsers at all if your situation allows, use background http objects for data sending, scraping etc. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158633/how-can-i-send-an-http-post-request-to-a-server-from-excel-using-vba

Comment: @PEH .....thanks for your suggestion. Let me explore this.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like:

`Application.SendKeys("Ok")`

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.