# How can I convert a Curl command into a WinHttpRequest object in vba excel

Tags: excel, vba, curl, winhttp

Given a Curl command :

**curl https://URL 

-u xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx: 

-X POST 

-F "source_file=@/tmp/my.doc" 

-F "DoSomething=checkit"**

The expected result is a Json string.
How can this be used in VBA Excel macro utilizing a "WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1" object.
Is the file "my.doc"  transfered by name or by a Byte array ?

I manged to convers a simple Curl command:

**curl https://URL 

-u xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:**

into the following code which works fine.

> ```
> With CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
>     .Open "GET", URL, False
>     .SetCredentials "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "", 0
>     .send
>     If .Status <> 200 Then
>         If MsgBox(.responseText, vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Error") = vbOK Then
>             Exit Sub
>         End If
>     Else
>         ss = .responseBody
>         BodyData = StrConv(ss, vbUnicode)
>         Set Json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(BodyData)
>     End If
> ```

The same is needed for the above Curl command.
Please help .

Comment: I have tried with the following code :

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to modify and add a few more parameters for the POST request. Try adapting using this example, and let us know what the errors are if you get any.

[POST request with win http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158633/how-can-i-send-an-http-post-request-to-a-server-from-excel-using-vba)

Comment: I tryed implementing the above Curl code in VBA Excel with the following code :